# Can transit in Japan or korea

Tags: indian-citizens, japan, layovers, south-korea, transit-visas

I am traveling to Vladivostok from India. I have a flight from India to Japan to Korea to Vladivostok. Can I transit in Japan or Korea? I hold an Indian passport.

Comment: What passport do you hold? Indian passport?

Comment: ... and more importantly, do you intend to leave the airport