# transit visa for indian passport holder in Daegu or Busan (South Korea) on the way to Khabarovsky or Vladivostok (Russia)

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, paperwork, transit-visas, south-korea

I have an **Indian** passport, **Japanese** residence card and intend to visit Khabarovsk and Vladivostok (**Russia**) but an itinerary (the cheapeast one) involves a transit in Daegu (TAE) or Busan (PUS). I have a valid US Visa (B1/B2) but that won't help in any way i guess.

I couldn't tell from Timatic whether I need to apply for a transit visa in advance or whether a visa-free transit (or on arrival) is feasible. I have checked the other post ([Can transit in Japan or korea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56819/can-transit-in-japan-or-korea)) but it is closed without a solution. I know that Indian passport holders can visit Jeju (CJU) but not Seoul (ICN), and can transit in Seoul(ICN) if certain conditions are met, but unclear about Daegu (TAE) or Busan (PUS).

In this case, i will possess a valid e-visa for Russia, as Timatic says:

> Nationals of India who travel to Blagoveshchensk (BQS), Khabarovsk (KHV), Petropavlovsk (PKC), Vladivostok (VVO) or
>     Yuzhno-Sakhalinsk (UUS), can obtain an e-visa before
>     departure at https://electronic-visa.kdmid.ru/index_en.html

(application form at https://evisa.kdmid.ru/)

Qn 1. Please clarify the rules applicable for a transit in Daegu, and guide how to apply if visa applications are required prior to the trip.

The itinerary for KHV via TAE is as follows:

Flight **TW212**, NRT->TAE

Flight **TW437**, TAE->KHV

Flight **TW438**, KHV->TAE

Flight **TW211**, TAE->NRT

The itinerary for VVO via PUS is as follows:

Flight **KE714**, NRT->PUS

Flight **KE5989**, PUS->VVO

Flight **KE5990**, VVO->PUS

Flight **KE715**, PUS->NRT

Qn 2. If i were to transit in ICN instead of TAE/PUS (flight sequence TYO-ICN-KHV/VVO-ICN-TYO), i don't require any transit visa applications, is that correct?

Comment: Are those trips in a single booking?

Comment: @Coke yes. Single booking, same airline, entire roundtrip

Comment: I have booked ticket from Japan to Bangkok . Transit at Daegu . But at check in counter told me that I need transit visa aT Daegu. They have not given ticket. I was in big trouble. Travel agent had not told me about the visa requirements at transit. Be careful

Comment: What airline? Was your connecting flight leaving Daegu on the same day?

Comment: I have booked ticket from Japan to India. Transit at Daegu. TWay airlines. I had the connection flight(same airlines) leaving Daegu on the same day. At check in counter told me that I need transit visa aT Daegu. They have not given ticket. Wasted money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIMATIC states:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day.

(this applies to all South Korean Airports except ICN, where you can also transit overnight within 24 hours)

So you don't need a visa to transit at TAE or PUS, if your connections are on the same day.